# Problems pointing site to site in Hosts file

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-7, localhost, hosts-file

I'm on my localhost PC.  I need to add an entry that maps our public site to our dev server.

I tried several things with no luck:

192.168.1.40 oursite.com // where the IP here is our internal dev server
or
devserver oursite.com
oursite.com devserver

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that oursite.com is different than www.oursite.com, so make sure to include the full domain name in the host file. Also your browser and OS will cache dns responses, so you may need to clear the browser cache and run `ipconfig -flushdns` on the command line before the host file response starts working.

Comment: I just don't know which above that I tried is the correct syntax.  Thanks.

Comment: is it IP space domain name where IP is the Ip you want to point the domain name to?

Comment: Yes.. IP then space or tab then domain name. See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U-N9cryU_fQ

Comment: Nice. I did not realize we registered our domain name with www or without the www and that made all the difference when specifying it in the hosts file...it has to be the one you registered...include or not to include the www is where the problem lied.

Comment: Just fyi you still register oursite.com, but in terms of DNS and Host files `www.oursite.com` is different than `oursite.com`. Most people have them point to the same IP address or have one be a CNAME of the other, but just remember that they are not the same thing and the host file needs either entries for both or just one entry for whichever version you type into your browers.

Answer (score 2):

HI Coffee,

For the sake of being thorough, the "// where the IP here is our internal...etc." is not in the actual hosts file right?

Not sure if you are doing this already, but you you should ping "oursite.com" after adding that line in your hostfile, if it responds from 192.168.1.40 you know the hosts file is working and perhaps its a host header or other webserver issue that preventing it from displaying in your browser.

Cheers, iain

Comment: no the // was just for this post...showing a comment..it's not in the hosts file.